# How large is the blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I've been trying to download the blockchain for days now...

My chaindata folder is currently at 12.5 GB...just how large is this blockchain?

Answer (score 8):

This question has been asked *ad nauseam*, as a cursory search would show.

- [What is the actual blockchain size?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13452/what-is-the-actual-blockchain-size)
- [Blockchain size projections](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4497/blockchain-size-projections)
- [As of Feb 2016, how big is the ethereum blockchain size and its monthly growth rate?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/798/as-of-feb-2016-how-big-is-the-ethereum-blockchain-size-and-its-monthly-growth-r)
- [Ethereum blockchain size as of March 2017 (geth --fast and others)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/ethereum-blockchain-size-as-of-march-2017-geth-fast-and-others)
- [The exact size of Ethereum full node blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16176/the-exact-size-of-ethereum-full-node-blockchain)
- [What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs/828#828)
- [Ethereum chain size](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13696/ethereum-chain-size)
- [Geth Chaindata size](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/geth-chaindata-size)

---

Let's quickly look at the headline question:

> How large is the blockchain?

It depends. But currently in the region of tens of GB.

It depends on:

- Which implementation of the client you're using (e.g. Geth, Parity, the C++ client, etc). I believe they all store the chaindata differently.
- Which pruning mode you've used, if any.
- Your hardware. Different types of filesystems are composed of different sized blocks. There is always some wasted space in those blocks. More wasted space means more disk space is used. (This is perhaps less important than the other things in the list. It's really just to hightlight that part of the blame *can* lie at the feet of the user, rather than the software.)

---

Two pertinent questions:

- Why are you downloading the blockchain data?
- Are you complaining about the size of the data, or the amount of time it takes to download?

---

**Why are you downloading the data?**

You don't *have* to. There are various ways of using the platform without running a full node yourself. Let someone else do it.

- [How can I read from and write to the blockchain without having a full node?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12874/how-can-i-read-from-and-write-to-the-blockchain-without-having-a-full-node)
- [Are there any public/free nodes to connect a Dapp front end?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/517/are-there-any-public-free-nodes-to-connect-a-dapp-front-end?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(These answers mention DAPPs, but the same general ideas apply. Also take a look at services like [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/).)

Are you planning to mine? In which case you're in for the long term, and an initial investment in time would be more than compensated by potential mining rewards. If you're mining, then presumably your machine is above average spec, and disk space is less of an issue than for an average user.

Do you want to run your own wallet? In which case, again, an initial investment in time and hardware is balanced by the ability to look after your own funds. Again, though, you don't *need* to run a full node to create a wallet.

Do you want to develop smart contracts? In which case, again, you don't need to run a full node. Have a look into how MetaMask interacts with the public Infura full node.

---

**Are you complaining about the size of the data, or the amount of time it takes to download?**

Blockchain technology has been around for a while now. Bitcoin's blockchain is 120GB, and Bitcoin is more popular than ever. The technology inherently involves and ever-increasing set of data.

Memory (non-volatile memory) is cheap. SSDs are cheaper than they've ever been. Having a machine with a couple of TB disks is relatively normal now.

It's quite possible that the size and cheapness of disk space will increase more rapidly than Ethereum's blockchain size. (Perhaps... ) Have a look at [Kryder's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Kryder#Kryder.27s_law_projection).

Have you looked into the various pruning modes available? Have you looked into the  `--fast` and `--light` options? Yes, these are perhaps less friendly than just plugging-and-playing, and your average user might not want to care about this, but we're still in the Wild West, and things are perhaps not as user-friendly as they will be in future.

With regards to the time it's taking to download, this is, in theory, an initial one-off investment to take part in the network. Why shouldn't it take this long? This is a new technology that still has certain barriers to entry. In future those barriers may be lower, but for now this is what we have.

Some rather more pragmatic questions. What's your bandwidth like? Are you behind a firewall or NAT box? Have you ensured the relevant ports are forwarded and unhindered? How many peers are you connected to? How long does it normally take you to download this amount of data?

Downloading the chaindata takes a while. It's annoying. But there are ways around it, and it's (hopefully) a one-off event.